# Meaning meaning

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

Could someone please help me out of the misunderstanding problem below?

Empowering the underprivileged lies in assuring them that education holds the real source of power

Comment: What research have you already done? Have you found any possible answers yet?

Comment: What is the misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

The way to improve the quality of life of the poor is to make them understand that
education is their way out of poverty, and the way to take control of their lives.

Answer (score 1):

One can gift the poor people with a belief that education gives a real power.